# Vue/Javascript - Sort array of objects based on its existence in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, vuejs2

I have two arrays, array1 has all objects and array2 has filtered objects based on a search string.

Currently I am rendering array2 (which will contain all objects from array1 when the search string is empty, but will return only filtered objects if search string isn't empty) to the user but I would like to show all objects and style the filtered ones (those which match the search) differently and keep those matching the search query in the top of the array/list and if I even in addition to that could also sort those matched objects alphabetically I would love to.

Here is how I am filtering based on the search query:

```
export default {
    name: "RegionSelector",
  
    data: () => ({
      searchRegionTextValue: "",
  
      regions: [
        {
          country: "USA",
          flag: "flag-en-us",
          name: "United States",
          language: "English",
        },
        {
          country: "UK",
          flag: "flag-en-gb",
          name: "United Kingdom",
          language: "English",
        },
        {
          country: "DE",
          flag: "flag-de",
          name: "Germany",
          language: " German",
        },
      ],
    }),
  
    methods: {
      // Used in my v-for in the template to style non-matched results differently
      checkRegion(region) {
        var isInArray =
          this.filteredRegions.find(function(el) {
            return el === region;
          }) !== undefined;
        return isInArray;
      },
  
    computed: {
      filteredRegions() {
        function compare(a, b) {
          if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
          if (a.name > b.name) return 1;
  
          return 0;
        }
  
        let regions = this.regions.filter((region) => {
          return (
            region.name
              .toLowerCase()
              .indexOf(this.searchRegionTextValue.toLowerCase()) != -1 ||
            region.language
              .toLowerCase()
              .indexOf(this.searchRegionTextValue.toLowerCase()) != -1
          );
        });
  
        regions.sort(compare);
  
        return regions;
      },
    },
};
```

And in my template I am rendering them this way (to show all objects but style them differently):

```
<div v-for="region in regions">
    <span
    :class="checkRegion(region) ? 'matched-query' : 'unmatched-query'">
        {{region.name}}
    </span>
</div>
```

How can I implement the sorting as mentioned above?

Comment: Your question (and problem space) is less about Vue rendering and more about data structure manipulation. Please consider completely removing any mention of Vue (you clearly know how to render a list) and provide both starting objects/lists and what the resulting data structure will look like. That way the focus is on the real issue and not Vue rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the spread operator to append the original array to the result of the filtered array like this

```js
[...filteredRegions(), ...regions]
```

This adds the matches to the beginning of the array, next we remove duplicates from the array, and we can do that just by wrapping the `new Set()` around it, just like this

```js
const newRegions = new Set([...filteredRegions(), ...regions])
```

You can convert it to a plain array just like this.

```js
const newRegions = [...new Set([...filteredRegions(), ...regions])]
```

**See Example code below:**

```js
const regions = [
  {
    country: "USA",
    flag: "flag-en-us",
    name: "United States",
    language: "English",
  },
  {
    country: "UK",
    flag: "flag-en-gb",
    name: "United Kingdom",
    language: "English",
  },
  {
    country: "DE",
    flag: "flag-de",
    name: "Germany",
    language: " German",
  },
  {
    country: "NG",
    flag: "flag-ng",
    name: "Nigeria",
    language: "English",
  },
]

function compare(a, b) {
  if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
  if (a.name > b.name) return 1;

  return 0;
}

function filteredRegions(query = 'Nigeria') {
  let regions = regions.filter((region) => {
    return (
      region.name
        .toLowerCase()
        .indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) != -1 || region.language
        .toLowerCase()
        .indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) != -1
    );
  });

  regions.sort(compare);

  return regions;
}

let result = [...new Set([...filteredRegions(), ...regions])]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce a second `computed` method which contain the un-matched objects and do another `for loop` for that array

Or

'might be' more efficiently, introduce another property to flag the object as matched object, and also use that property for the sorting logic

```
computed: {
  newregions() {
    function compare(a, b) {
      if (a.matched && !b.matched) return -1;
      if (!a.matched && b.matched) return 1;
      if (a.matched && b.matched) {
        if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
        if (a.name > b.name) return 1;
      }

      return 0;
    }

    let regions = this.regions.map((region) => ({
      ...region,
      matched: region.name
          .toLowerCase()
          .indexOf(this.searchRegionTextValue.toLowerCase()) != -1 ||
        region.language
          .toLowerCase()
          .indexOf(this.searchRegionTextValue.toLowerCase()) != -1
    }));

    regions.sort(compare);

    return regions;
  },
},
```

and then on your template

```
<div v-for="region in newregions">
    <span
    :class="region.matched ? 'matched-query' : 'unmatched-query'">
        {{region.name}}
    </span>
</div>
```